# SQL Server - return most recent date of records including NULLs?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to return the most recent date for records and have an INNER JOIN like this:

```
 INNER JOIN ( SELECT ID, MAX(RegDate) AS RegDate
 FROM   dbo.registrations
 GROUP BY ID
  ) RI ON app.ID= RI.ID
  AND dbo.registrations.RegDate= RI.RegDate
```

This works fine and it returns all records with the highest dates and removes records that do not have the highest date.

However some records have NULL values in the RegDate. How can I return these records as well?

If I set the join to LEFT OUTER JOIN all dates are returned instead of the highest dates.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `OR dbo.registrations.RegDate IS NULL` condition

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID,
                    Max(RegDate) AS RegDate
            FROM   dbo.registrations
            GROUP  BY ID) RI
        ON app.ID = RI.ID
            AND ( dbo.registrations.RegDate = RI.RegDate
                    OR dbo.registrations.RegDate IS NULL ) --Here
```